# What does Netstat -tlnp mean and do

Tags: netstat

What does netstat -tlnp do and mean? I have read the man pages for netstat however can only find a answer for -l not the other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo netstat -tlnp
# t : Show TCP sockets only
# l : Show LISTENING sockets only
# n : Show numerical addresses
# p : Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs
```

For more information see the man page
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/netstat.8.html